# Wordpress вывод постов

Tags: wordpress

Ни как не могу записать условие, есть вывод постов, но у первого стоит дополнительно класс col-lg-offset-1, а у последующих нету.Как записать что если это первый пост ему нужно добавить этот класс.Я так понимаю нужно задать переменную равную например 1 и сравнить есть первый пост === 1 то добавить ему класс

```
               <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
           <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="tour_block_cel col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="block_tour">
                    <div class="img_tour1 text-center">
                        <a href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <p class="button"><a class="btn btn-success" role="button">book now</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
    $count=0;?>
    <div class="tour_block_cel col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $count=count+1;
                    //здесь вывод контента
        if (is_int($count==1)) {
        echo ('</div><div class="tour_block_cel col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">');
        };
    endwhile; 
    endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

я так реализовывал других путей не нашел

Comment: спасиб, добрый человек!